# How to simulate a touch on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, simulate

I would like to know if there isn't any method which will allow me to simulate a touch/click/pressure (call it as you want) on iOS.
I don't know if I have something to add about this... Except that I'm coding with Objective-c.

Every help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the method that allow me to have the coordinates of the case that I've selected (it show me in the log) :

```
- (void)collectionViewTableLayoutManager:(DRCollectionViewTableLayoutManager *)manager collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectCellAtRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"SELECTED: %ld.%ld / %ld.%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row, (long)row, (long)column); 
}
```

Here is my method who handle the dragNdrop of my PostIt (see in the comments for more info):

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

//Here to know the coordinates of the drop
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){        
    CGPoint centerPointOfView = [recognizer locationInView:self.superview];
    NSLog(@"X - %f, Y - %f",centerPointOfView.x,centerPointOfView.y);
}

[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];
}
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: So, I've got an object (a PostIt exactly, which come from my nib SelectPostIt.xib). This one is draggable. Then I have a collection view with multiple cases. When I select one of these case, it return to me the coordinates of this one (that allow me to identify the case in question). I'm also able to have the last coordinates of my PostIt when I dragNdrop it (in fact the coordinates of the drop). What I want to do is, when I drop one PostIt on one case, it will simulate a click with the coordinates of the drop and show me on which case I've dropped the PostIt.

Comment: so you want to call method on click?

Comment: It could be a solution yes you're right... But how can I do that? I'll edit my post and add the method that allow me to have the coordinates of my case.

Comment: normally you wire your tappable objects with an IBAction in Interface Builder. But there's nothing preventing from calling the IBAction method directly when the drag & drop finishes. Just identify which collection item was used and pass it as the sender to your IBAction

Comment: you got any event when you dragNdrop so there you have to call method so you can get which case you droped

Comment: call method like this [buttonDown addTarget:self action:@selector(quantityDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  and   - (void)quantityDown:(id)sender  
    {    
       NSLog(@"%d", sender.tag);  
    }

Comment: So do I need to call a method when I drop my PostIt? I'll add my method who handle the dragNdrop and show me the coordinates of the drop.

Comment: yes do here what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved my problem. Initially, the method who handle the postIt's dragNdrop was in the postIt.m . So I moved it into my viewController.m . Now, from this method, I'm able to pick up the CollectionView of my viewController and "simulate" a click.

Here is how my new method looks like:

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

//the coordinates of the drop
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    CGPoint centerPointOfView = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"X - %f, Y - %f",centerPointOfView.x,centerPointOfView.y);

    //Here is how I pick up the cell where the post it has been dropped
    [_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:centerPointOfView]];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:centerPointOfView];

//some log tests
    NSLog(@"SELECTED: %ld.%ld ", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
}


[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```